# Cannot redirect to another route inside html view file codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, frameworks

```
<?php
$checkNotNull = checkNotNull($user_detail->user_id);
$logged_data = $this->session->userdata('logged');

if(!$checkNotNull && $logged_data['status'] == 1){
 header("location:".base_url()."accounts/kyc");
}

if (!$this->session->userdata('lang')) {
    $this->lang->load(DEFAULT_LANG, LANG_FOLDER);
} else {
    $lang_data = $this->session->userdata('lang');
    $this->lang->load($lang_data['language'] . '_lang', $lang_data['language']);
}


?>
```

I am tring to redirect to another route if the checkNotNull variable is false and user has logged in.
I have used every technique to redirect but it is not helping out.Variable are checked thoroughly and the response is coming expected but when I use header function redirect function it goes to error page and shows too many redirects.
I am using codeigniter.

Comment: Where is $user_detail coming from?

Comment: $user_detail is coming from my existing code and in this there is just user id which is coming.

Comment: Everything looks good, I'm just thinkging that the 2 items are not set properly.  Var_dump them out.